# How does AraMorph 1.2.1 work?

Tags: nlp, tagging

I have downloaded [AraMorph 1.2.1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/aramorph/) Perl version from SourceForge, but I do not know how to use it. Could someone explain to me how can I get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Aramorph is an Arabic language analyzer .It is developed by Bulkwater ,open source code with perl script !!You input your text file in Arabic language then got the translation in English
and the diact. (Accent short vowels in arabic for huge database).I have some comments on the program despite it is useful.I am working now on developing the same program with .NET ,it is not easy ,but I am trying !!!If you want more information ,please let me know .Thank you
Mohammed Al Otoom

Comment: Thanks for your interest Mr.Otoom. Actually i am preparing for the my senior project for the next semester and it will be a framework for Arabic language(Morphology,tagger,parser and may be semantic). I am eager to start such project because there is no easy and fast framework for Arabic language. For this reason i am so interested in natural language processing projects. We have not start coding yet, but we read many papers about such topics. Our project will use C++. Thanks. Hani Almousli....

Answer (score -1):

I can't tell you much about aramorph, but we sell and support an Arabic Morphological Analysis capability. So since no one turned up to answer your question, I don't feel like I'm doing anything too offensive to suggest that you have a look at our stuff. www.basistech.com.